# Exposed Filters: Is there a way to know how often a query has been run?

Tags: views, search, log-messages

I would like to know if it's possible to get the statistics from an exposed filter. For example, if I have a job website, is it possible to get data about which jobs people are searching the most using the exposed form? It would help if I need to improve the quality of the website.